# IE's msxml and possible violation of the same origin policy

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I came across a curious case of what seems like a violation of the same origin policy in IE when using msxml. Here is a complete example:

```
var xmlhttp=false;  
try
{
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");      
 }
catch (e)
{
  try
  {
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");       
  } catch (E)
  {
   xmlhttp = false;
  }
}    
if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp=false;
    }
}

if (!xmlhttp && window.createRequest) {
    try {
        xmlhttp = window.createRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp=false;
    }
}
function doRequest()
{
    xmlhttp.open('GET','http://www.google.com',true);       
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){                
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
                 alert(xmlhttp.responseText);       
            }
        };  
}
```

Calling the doRequest() method from a simple onClick event in IE will happily get you the contents of google.com no matter which domain the page is hosted on. Isn't this a violation of same origin? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried another domain beside google.com?  I have a feeling Google may have allowed access to some resources which lets this work.

Comment: It doesn't matter which domain you use. This is a restriction enforced by the browser